# JSF PrimeFace: p repeat ajax update with class not working

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

totalListSumA is an ArrayList inside java. Inside debug mode, the arraylist work just fine. New value assigned into this list.

When user input a new value in a box, program will recalculate new sum and display inside the code shown below.

```
                        <p:inputNumber 
                            class="caseType1"
                            rendered="#{inputFormTemplateView.allowEdit}" 
                            inputStyle="text-align: center"                             
                            minValue="0"
                            maxValue="99999999"                             
                            decimalPlaces="0"
                            thousandSeparator=""
                            emptyValue=""
                            value="#{inputFormView.selectedInputFormDetail.data[dataField]}" >
                            <p:ajax update="dataField, #{inputForm4_1View.getColTotal()}"/>
                            <p:ajax update="@(.totalRow3)"></p:ajax>
                        </p:inputNumber> 


        <tr>
            <td align='center'>Total</td>
                <p:repeat var="item" value="#{inputForm4_1View.totalListSumA}" class="totalRow3">
                <td class="cell_cal" style='text-align:center;' >
                        <h:outputLabel 
                            class="totalRow3"
                            value="#{item}" />
                </td>
                </p:repeat> 
        </tr>
```

I have tried

- h:panelGroup id='...'
- ui:repeat id='....'

Still the value remain unchanged inside p:repeat. Any method I can try to get and show the latest value inside totalListSumA?

Comment: Hi, 1:please read [tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). 2:Most likele off-topic but your html is 'invalid', you have a nested `<td>`. 3: Two `p:ajax` both without `event` attribute (so both with the default event) also results in not the right behaviour 4:Please create a real [mcve] 5:Post version info 6: also read the [JSF info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info)

Comment: You are using 3 different beans/parameters in your sample.  1)inputFormTemplateView  2)inputFormView 3)inputForm4_1View  Is this correct?
In `update=` you are using `#{inputForm4_1View.getColTotal()}`? update needs ids of html elements.

Comment: @Holger: The EL in there might work if it is really intended I used it once like that too in a very specific case But, like you, I doubt it is intentional here)

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong

```
<p:ajax update="dataField, #{inputForm4_1View.getColTotal()}"/>
<p:ajax update="@(.totalRow3)"></p:ajax>
```

1) Ajax should have event="change" or other events, but most wrong thing is that calling bean method inside update.

2) Use `listener="#{inputForm4_1View.getColTotal()}"`

3) Don't use 2 same ajaxes.

Solution:

```
<p:ajax event="change" update="dataField, @(.totalRow3)" listener="#{inputForm4_1View.getColTotal()}"/>
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, try update form like `update="@form"` or `update="yourFormId"`